# How to turn off red-blue outlines (like chromatic aberration) on a font?

Tags: html, css

[A screenshot of the same font on 2 different pages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9YYWy.jpg)

index.php doesn't have these red and blue outlines, but a subpage(project page) has.
Do you know how to turn it off?
I already tried to add to HTML and/or body this:

```
-webkit-font-smoothing: antialised;
```

But it hasn't helped. Both pages are still different, one with outlines another without them.
I would be very thankful if you help to get rid of these outlines or at least add them everywhere.

Comment: That's not chromatic aberration, that's subpixel antialiasing. Depends on the browser and OS.

Comment: Check [this link - Improving Font Rendering With CSS](https://betterprogramming.pub/improving-font-rendering-with-css-3383fc358cbc) or short answer in stackoverflow https://stackoverflow.com/a/22990803/14135825

Comment: @Greg, thank you very much. It is gonna help. I am starting to read it.

Comment: @AKX Thank you for your comment. Yeah, of course it is not chromatic aberration ) There are no lenses here. That is just the first what comes to mind when you see it. I've changed the title to be more correct. Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to render thin fonts more smoothly in CSS 3 on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22769474/how-to-render-thin-fonts-more-smoothly-in-css-3-on-windows)

Comment: @HereticMonkey It looks like it answers, but in the reality it doesn't. I don't know why, but on one page there is antializing on another there is no, I try to add the styles from your links to <html> or <body> into my code but it doesn't help. Pages are still different. I will leave it for now, because it is almost unnoticeable. But of course that is not super good. Probably I need to look better into my code.